# Valor do char* é mostrado mesmo onde não foi chamado usando Arduino

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Isto é exatamente o que estou usando:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};

  // Tentativa frustada, possui o mesmo problema:
  //uint32_t i;
  //uint8_t* TotalRequisicao;
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////

int i;
char* TotalRequisicao;

IPAddress ip(192, 166, 0, 23);
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();

  Serial.print("IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

}

void loop(){

  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if(client){

      while(client.connected()){

              Serial.println("Novo cliente!");

              i = 0;
              TotalRequisicao = "";

              while(char LerRequisicao = client.read()){

                  if(LerRequisicao == '\n'){

                      Serial.println();
                      Serial.println(TotalRequisicao);
                      break; 

                  }else{

                      TotalRequisicao[i] = LerRequisicao;
                      i++;

                  }

              }

              client.println();     
              client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
              client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
              client.println("Connection: close");
              client.println();
              client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
              client.println("<html>");
              client.println("<head>");
              client.println("</head>");
              client.println("</html>");


              break;


    }

  delay(1);
  client.stop();

  }

}
```

### Resultados:

Isso é o que está ocorrendo executando algumas requisições para o IP.

**No Serial Monitor, do Arduino:**

```
IP: 192.166.0.23
Novo cliente!

GET / HTTP/1.1
nte!GET / HTTP/1.1
nte!
GET / HTTP/1.1
nte!HTTP/1.1
nte!
GET / HTTP/1.1
nte!
```

**Na resposta da requisição:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!HTTP/1.1 200 OK
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!Content-Type: text/html
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!Connection: close
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!<!DOCTYPE HTML>
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!<html>
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!<head>
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!</head>
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!</html>
GET / HTTP/1.1nte!
```

---

### Respostas esperadas:

Isso era o que para mim seria o desejado, entenda como o objetivo do código acima:

**No Serial Monitor, do Arduino:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

**Na resposta da requisição:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
</html>
```

---

Estou usando o [Ethernet Shield V1](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShieldV1) e também teste com o [Módulo W5100](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Ethernet) em um Arduino UNO, ambos deram ruim. Entretanto o problema está sendo causado pelo `char* TotalRequisicao`, uma vez que tornando ele um comentário `//TotalRequisicao[i] = LerRequisicao;` o problema não é apresentado, porém o objetivo também não é atingido. :<

Minha ideia com o `TotalRequisicao[i] = LerRequisicao;` seria de obter inteiramente o `GET / HTTP/1.1` numa só "string" (um `char*`), dessa forma tornando mais fácil para identificar qual página/arquivo foi chamado.

Porém por algum motivo a informação do `TotalRequisição` possui alguma "colisão" e se espalhar por outros locais onde a variável nunca foi sequer chamada.

*PS: Mesmo removendo o `Serial.println(TotalRequisicao);`, mas mantendo o `TotalRequisicao[i] = LerRequisicao;` o problema persiste.*

Qual seria o motivo para isso e como pode ser corrigido?

Answer (score 1):

**O motivo e a explicação do porque isso ocorreu ainda não sei, sinceramente, o que de fato é um problema**, *afinal isso pode se repetir e não irei saber o porque.*

---

Entretanto a solução foi utilizar [`readStringUntil('\n');`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil) e aparentemente isto corrigiu o problema.

Desta forma bastou utilizar:

```
TotalRequisicao = client.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Além disso mudar para `String`:

```
String TotalRequisicao;
```

Isso agora retornou `GET / HTTP/1.1` no "console" e retornou apenas o HTML (e o Header) para o cliente. ;)